# How can I stop the WPF ProgressBar pulsing/animating when it reaches 100%?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, progress-bar

I have an MVVM-based WPF 4 application which uses a [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) to show the percentage completion of a long-running operation.

```
<ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar"
    IsIndeterminate="False"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="100"
    Value="{Binding Path=ProgressPercentageComplete, Mode=OneWay}"
    Visibility="Visible"/>
```

I am happy for the "pulsing" animation to occur while the progress bar is moving, but once it reaches 100% I'd like it to stop animating and just remain static at 100%.

I've tried setting `IsIndeterminate="False"` but this doesn't help and I can see why after reading the MSDN Documentation:

> When this property is true, the
>   ProgressBar animates a few bars moving
>   across the ProgressBar in a continuous
>   manner and ignores the Value property.

**Is it possible to stop this animation? Either completely, or just at 100%.**

Comment: Killing the pulsating visual is a bad idea as the UI reasoning is that it provides continuous user feedback; to avoid the user believing something has locked up and is no longer responding.

Comment: Applications lock up with UI animations still running all the time.  It takes more than that to persuade a user that the app is still alive.

Comment: @RobertRossney, I purposefully locked up my UI thread and *poof*, the animation stopped, giving immediate feedback.  aaron-mciver is right that the pulsation has a UX purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by copying the entire `ControlTemplate` for the `ProgressBar`, then add a `Trigger` for the condition where `ProgressBar.Value=100`. The XAML as is will make the `ProgressBar` behave as it does now. Remove the comment Tags at the bottom and the animation will stop when the `ProgressBar`'s Value property reaches 100. The only weakness is, that when you change the Maximum Property of the `ProgressBar` you need to change the Trigger as well. Anyone know how to bind the Trigger to the actual value of the Maximum Property?

```
<Window x:Class="ProgressBarSpike.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBackground" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#BABABA" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#C7C7C7" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#BABABA" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#B2B2B2" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#8C8C8C" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarGlassyHighlight" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#50FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarTopHighlight" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.05"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.25"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF" Offset="0.4"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeLeft" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#0C000000" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.3"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeRight" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.7"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#0C000000" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectLeft" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" RelativeTransform="1,0,0,1,0.5,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffect" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectRight" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" RelativeTransform="1,0,0,1,-0.5,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorGlassyHighlight" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#90FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyleStopAnimation" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#01D328"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarGlassyHighlight}" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#80FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTopHighlight}" Margin="1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="1"/>
                            <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1">
                                <Grid x:Name="Foreground">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="true">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-100,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid x:Name="Overlay">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="LeftDark" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeLeft}" Margin="1,1,0,1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="RightDark" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeRight}" Margin="0,1,1,1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="LeftLight" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectLeft}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="CenterLight" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffect}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="RightLight" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectRight}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                        <Border x:Name="Highlight1" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorGlassyHighlight}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                        <Border x:Name="Highlight2" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTopHighlight}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Decorator>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="TemplateRoot">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LeftDark" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="RightDark" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LeftLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CenterLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="RightLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Animation" Value="#80B5FFA9"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!--
                            <Trigger Property="Value" Value="100">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Animation" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            -->

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ProgressBar Name="Progress"  Height="50" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarStyleStopAnimation}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do not specify `Value="100"` explicitly? Because this approach is not universal. It makes me to set `Maximum` of any `ProgressBar` as "100". I tried to use `Binding` but it does't work :(

Comment: One should seriously consider Dave Clemmer's answer (see below) as alternative since replacing the control template has also some drawbacks as Dave notes.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a generalized solution for this using an attached property, allowing me to toggle the behavior on any `ProgressBar` simply through a direct property or style setter, like so:

```
<ProgressBar helpers:ProgressBarHelper.StopAnimationOnCompletion="True" />
```

The code:

```cs
public static class ProgressBarHelper {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StopAnimationOnCompletionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StopAnimationOnCompletion", typeof(bool), typeof(ProgressBarHelper),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnStopAnimationOnCompletionChanged));

    public static bool GetStopAnimationOnCompletion(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        return (bool)progressBar.GetValue(StopAnimationOnCompletionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetStopAnimationOnCompletion(ProgressBar progressBar, bool value) {
        progressBar.SetValue(StopAnimationOnCompletionProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnStopAnimationOnCompletionChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var progressBar = obj as ProgressBar;
        if (progressBar == null) return;

        var stopAnimationOnCompletion = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (stopAnimationOnCompletion) {
            progressBar.Loaded += StopAnimationOnCompletion_Loaded;
            progressBar.ValueChanged += StopAnimationOnCompletion_ValueChanged;
        } else {
            progressBar.Loaded -= StopAnimationOnCompletion_Loaded;
            progressBar.ValueChanged -= StopAnimationOnCompletion_ValueChanged;
        }

        if (progressBar.IsLoaded) {
            ReevaluateAnimationVisibility(progressBar);
        }
    }

    private static void StopAnimationOnCompletion_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ReevaluateAnimationVisibility((ProgressBar)sender);
    }

    private static void StopAnimationOnCompletion_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e) {
        var progressBar = (ProgressBar)sender;

        if (e.NewValue == progressBar.Maximum || e.OldValue == progressBar.Maximum) {
            ReevaluateAnimationVisibility(progressBar);
        }
    }

    private static void ReevaluateAnimationVisibility(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        if (GetStopAnimationOnCompletion(progressBar)) {
            var animationElement = GetAnimationElement(progressBar);
            if (animationElement != null) {
                if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum) {
                    animationElement.SetCurrentValue(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
                } else {
                    animationElement.InvalidateProperty(UIElement.VisibilityProperty);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static DependencyObject GetAnimationElement(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        var template = progressBar.Template;
        if (template == null) return null;

        return template.FindName("PART_GlowRect", progressBar) as DependencyObject;
    }
}
```

Basically, it adds a `ValueChanged` handler which adjusts the visibility of the animated element.

A few notes:

- I'm using `"PART_GlowRect"` to find the animated element, although someone called this a hack. I disagree: this element name is officially documented through [TemplatePartAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx), which you can see in [ProgressBar's declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx). While it's true that this doesn't necessarily guarantee that the named element exists, the only reason it should be missing is if the animation feature isn't supported at all. If it is supported but uses a different element name than the one documented, I would consider that a bug, not an implementation detail.
- Since I'm pulling an element out of the template, it's also necessary to handle the `Loaded` event (which is raised when a template is applied) to wait for the template to become available before attempting to set initial visibility, and if necessary set it again when the template is replaced on the fly by a theme change.
- Rather than explicitly toggling `Visibility` between `Collapsed` and `Visible`, I'm using [SetCurrentValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) to set to `Collapsed`, and [InvalidateProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.invalidateproperty.aspx) to reset it. `SetCurrentValue` applies a value that does not take priority over other value sources, and `InvalidateProperty` re-evaluates the property without taking the `SetCurrentValue` setting into consideration. This ensures that if there are existing styles or triggers which would affect the visibility under normal conditions (i.e. when it is *not* at 100%), it would reset to that behavior if the progress bar is reused (going from 100% back to 0%) rather than being hard-coded to `Visible`.

Comment: It works fine, but how can I set solid color brush of progress bar like in previous answer?

Comment: @monstr You can't really do that reliably without replacing the entire control template. Theoretically you could override [OnApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) to find and modify the elements that make up the 3D look ("Animation" and "Overlay"), as I did with "PART_GlowRect". But these aren't guaranteed parts of the template, they may change depending on the current Windows theme.

Comment: I made it by adding some code in your `ReevaluateAnimationVisibility` method. I used `Animation` part of template, and verificated on null, so even there is no `Animation` part in current Windows theme - it will not cause of exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

Dabblernl's answer is robust.
Here is a hack (because it relies on the internal name of the element that does the glow, which is an implementation detail and may change in a subsequent version):

```
void SetGlowVisibility(ProgressBar progressBar, Visibility visibility) {
    var anim = progressBar.Template.FindName("Animation", progressBar) as FrameworkElement;
    if (anim != null)
        anim.Visibility = visibility;
}
```

If how a `ProgressBar` is implemented changes, this hack may stop working.

On the other hand, a solution that completely replaces the XAML and styles may lock-in and fix colours, borders etc. and disable behaviour that might be added to a newer version of the ProgressBar in the future...

**Edit:** The implementation detail did change. Changed `"PART_GlowRect"` to `"Animation"` -- the former is used only in `aero.normalcolor.xaml`, while the latter is used in more recent `aero2.normalcolor.xaml` and `aerolite.normalcolor.xaml` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the converter being used by `PART_Indicator` which by default is the `ProgressBarBrushConverter` which is where the animation is coming from...

```
...

TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
double num11 = num8 * 100;
DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(num11));
animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
for (int i = 1; i <= num8; i++)
{
    double num13 = i * num7;
    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(num13, KeyTime.Uniform));
}
transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animation);

...
```

The [default logic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/38a76137-2874-48ed-b7c2-53586e47274a/) for the `ProgressBarBrushConverter` can then be modified to suit your needs.

You may have to end up passing parameters to the converter so that it can check the value and provide the appropriate animation or lack thereof contingent on the state of the `ProgressBar`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to create a custom style for the `ProgressBar`.

The description of MSDN for *IsIndeterminate* refers to another behaviour and, for default, it is false so setting it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please improve the correctness of this answer telling the why of -1.