# Pulsing speed of a progress bar in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

The goal is to switch the flow of the progress bar and speed it up. I can easily change the flow (the pulsing highlight that travels within the bar, not the actual % value) by changing the FlowDirection to RightToLeft. I cannot however find out how to increase the speed of this highlight. I found various styles/templates that will let me change the color, size, shape, whatever, but nothing to do with the actual speed at which it travels.

Can someone point in a direction or give me an example of where I can look?

Comment: does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570865/how-can-i-stop-the-wpf-progressbar-pulsing-animating-when-it-reaches-100

Comment: perhaps using animation can help you achieve the same. could you share some code how you would speed up the progressbar.

Comment: @bdimag Well, unfortunately that link does not show me how to edit the pulsing animation besides hiding it. But it does let me know exactly what part I ought to be messing with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the behavior you are expecting on a scrollbar is not normally possible so I attempted to mimic the expected behavior using canvas

I added animation which moves and speeds up the progress bar

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness=".5" Height="13" CornerRadius="2" Margin="2">
        <Canvas Height="10" x:Name="canvas" Margin="1" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Rectangle Width="10" Fill="Green" Height="10" x:Name="rect"/>
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SizeChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rect" 
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" 
                                         To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas}"
                                         From="0"
                                         Duration="0:0:2">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
```

you can style it to a natural looking bar or even the way you like it.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helped me - I ended up with some key adjustments though. Instead of the canvas I used a grid, and I put the triggers on the rectangle targeting TranslateTransform X on Loaded.